# Is it safe to authorize user models using `instanceof` in JavaScript / TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, adonis.js, lucid

Let's say I have 3 models: Admin, User, Product (I'm using model classes)

Only an admin can ADD, UPDATE, DELETE a product and users can only GET products, so I have registered an ACL middleware for corresponding routes.

Now in my ACL middleware, I want to authorize users, and if they are **ADMIN**, I will call `next()` method, otherwise, I'm going to reject the request with a `401`.

I found it easy to do the check using JavaScript's `instanceof` operator:

```
const user = await auth.authenticate()

if (user instanceof Admin) {
  await next()
} else {
  throw UnAuthorizedUserException
}
```

*`await auth.authenticate()` returns the current user sending the request, be it a user or an admin*

However, I'm not sure if this is the safest way to distinguish b/w admins and users.

Now my question is, am I doing it right? Which approach is better than what I'm doing?

**Note (if it helps):** I'm using Adonis.js v5, TypeScript and Lucid models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this. You will need to be careful about inheritance patterns if you use this approach. You may want to consider adding a role property to the user object and using that for the check.

example using a role prop.

```
if (user.role === 'ADMIN') {
  ...
}
```

example of instanceof backfiring on you

```
class User {}
class Admin extends User {}

const user = new User;
const admin = new Admin;

console.log(user instanceof User); // true
console.log(user instanceof Admin); // false
console.log(admin instanceof User); // true **watch out for this**
console.log(admin instanceof Admin); // true
```

Comment: Thanks, So I gotta look into the ORM to see what's happening under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

> The `instanceof` operator tests to see if the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object. The return value is a boolean value.

So `user instanceof Admin` will test positive if `user` is `Admin` or its subclass instance. Using this pattern is very common in JS/TS world and is safe as long `auth.authenticate()` correctly authenticates users and `Admin` is the same class `authenticate` method returns.

Also in TypeScript `instanceof` is treated as [TypeGuard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types), so inside `if` block you can use `user` as `Admin` instance (for example if admin instance has more methods).

Comment: Thanks, So I gotta look into the ORM to see what's happening under the hood.